# HTML SELECT Tag Methods

Tags: html, select

I am a student and stuck in this code. I want to pass values selected by user in SELECT option to the function for calculation, I wrote following code but it is not accordingly:

```
    <html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>New Page 1</title>
</head>
<script language = vbscript>
function f1()
dim price, top, tot
top = 0
price = 0
if document.form1.R1(0).checked then
price = 200
else
price = 250
end if
if document.form1.D1.value = "Cheese" then
top = 50
end if
tot = price + tot
document.form1.T1.value = tot
end function
</script>
<body>

<form name = "form1" action="--WEBBOT-SELF--" method="POST">
    <!--webbot bot="SaveResults" U-File="_private/form_results.csv" S-Format="TEXT/CSV" S-Label-Fields="TRUE" -->
    <p>PIZZA CAFE</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="R1">Pan&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="R1">Crust</p>

    <p><select size="5" name="D1" multiple>
    <option>Cheese</option>
    <option>Capsicum</option>
    <option>Pepperoni</option>
    </select></p>

    <p>Total Price : <input type="text" name="T1" size="20"></p>
    <p><input type="button" value="Button" name="B3" onclick = "f1()">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="B2"></p>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

The above code is not giving any error but it is not accepting any input for further calculations.

Comment: Did you checked the JavaScript console error ?

Comment: your `option`s have no `value`s, e.g. `<option value="Cheese">Cheese</option>`

Comment: The options have no value *attributes*, they **do** have values: http://jsbin.com/losuburobi/1/edit?html,console

Comment: What browser are you testing this in? Nothing supports client side VBScript except Internet Explorer and [sometimes not even then](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn384057%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: I am doing this in Microsoft Front Page